# How can i auto adjust a text file into a csv file with proper indexing using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output txt file which i tried to convert into csv file using pandas but the text file formatting is somewhat complicated and the entire required text is being entered into a single column. How can i separate that text into respected columns ?

```
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
dataframe1.to_csv('sfa-data.csv',index = None)
```

The sample data in my txt file

```
****************************
*     Physical Disk(s)     *
****************************


Enclosure|                                       |S|                                                  |Health|                              |Block|
Idx |Pos |Slot| Vendor |     Product ID     |Type|E|Capacity  | RPM|Revision|    Serial Number   |Pool|State | Idx |State |       WWN       |Size |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    1    1 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KE9L                2  GOOD      6 NORM  + 5000cca039067a28   4K 
   1    1    2 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV333PJ                3  GOOD     18 NORM  + 5000cca03905a348   4K 
   1    1    3 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KELL                2  GOOD     10 NORM  + 5000cca039067a4c   4K 
   1    1    4 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KETL                2  GOOD     15 NORM  + 5000cca039067a64   4K 
   1    1    5 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KG1L                3  GOOD     24 NORM    5000cca039067a84   4K 
   1    1    6 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV37D5L                4  GOOD     36 NORM    5000cca03905e374   4K 
   1    1    8 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV349YL                3  GOOD     26 NORM    5000cca03905b554   4K 
   1    1    9 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KG2L                3  GOOD     25 NORM    5000cca039067a88   4K 
   1    1   10 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV366DL             UNAS  GOOD     42 READY   5000cca03905d1a4   4K 
   1    1   11 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV349ZL                4  GOOD     28 NORM    5000cca03905b558   4K 
   1    1   12 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV366JL             UNAS  GOOD     43 READY   5000cca03905d1b4   4K 
   1    1   13 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3B33L                1  GOOD      1 NORM  + 5000cca039061b20   4K 
   1    1   14 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV365ZL                4  GOOD     34 NORM    5000cca03905d170   4K 
   1    1   15 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS          0 B  15K B380     0XV3359J             UNAS   UNK      9 READY   5000cca03905a410  UNK 
   1    1   16 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KEXL                3  GOOD     19 NORM  + 5000cca039067a74   4K 
   1    1   17 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KE7L                2  GOOD      4 NORM  + 5000cca039067a20   4K 
   1    1   18 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3KEZL                3  GOOD     21 NORM  + 5000cca039067a7c   4K 
   1    1   19 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV335VJ                3  GOOD     22 NORM  + 5000cca03905a454   4K 
   1    1   20 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV3VTMJ                2  GOOD     11 NORM  + 5000cca0390706c8   4K 
   1    1   21 HGST     HUC156060CS4201       SAS Y  558.9 GiB  15K B380     0XV46WMJ                4  GOOD     30 NORM    5000cca03907ad68   4K
```

Comment: Is the text file always in the same format? The first 6 lines can be skipped and the header is always on the 7th line with ````--------```` always on the 8th line onwards with data separated by spaces (and no spaces within each column)?

Comment: So you have a fixed format file.  Did you attempt to tell python where the fields are in the lines?

Answer (score -1):

It's kinda ugly still, but certainly at a point that it could be cleaned up from here. Start by looking at the documentation for [pandas.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas-read-fwf)

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = ''.join(f.readlines()[6:])

lens = [x+1 for x in map(len, data[0].split('|'))]
df = pd.read_fwf(data, widths=lens)
print(df.head())
print(df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   Idx |  Pos |  Slot|   Vendor |       Product ID     |  Type|  E|  Capacity  |   RPM|  Revision|      Serial Number   |  Pool|  State | Idx |.1 State |.1         WWN       |  Size |  Unnamed: 17
0  -----  -----  -----  ---------  ---------------------  -----  --  -----------  -----  ---------  ---------------------  -----  -------  ------   -------  ------------------  ------          NaN
1      1      1      1       HGST        HUC156060CS4201    SAS   Y    558.9 GiB    15K       B380               0XV3KE9L      2     GOOD       6   NORM  +    5000cca039067a28      4K          NaN
2      1      1      2       HGST        HUC156060CS4201    SAS   Y    558.9 GiB    15K       B380               0XV333PJ      3     GOOD      18   NORM  +    5000cca03905a348      4K          NaN
3      1      1      3       HGST        HUC156060CS4201    SAS   Y    558.9 GiB    15K       B380               0XV3KELL      2     GOOD      10   NORM  +    5000cca039067a4c      4K          NaN
4      1      1      4       HGST        HUC156060CS4201    SAS   Y    558.9 GiB    15K       B380               0XV3KETL      2     GOOD      15   NORM  +    5000cca039067a64      4K          NaN
...
Index(['Idx |', 'Pos |', 'Slot|', 'Vendor |', 'Product ID     |', 'Type|',
       'E|', 'Capacity  |', 'RPM|', 'Revision|', 'Serial Number   |', 'Pool|',
       'State |', 'Idx |.1', 'State |.1', 'WWN       |', 'Size |',
       'Unnamed: 17'],
      dtype='object')
```